# jQuery Conflict twittmarquee

Tags: jquery

Hi I am very new to jQuery. I am having jQuery conflict in my website. I already tried adding the jQuery.noConflict() but still not working.

I got this code from a twittmarquee jquery. Can you help me, how to put no conflict in this script?..

```
<script>
var page={};
$(function(){
    new FrontPage().init();
}); 
</script>
```

Thanks, a lot..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use jquery as '$' in the given sample and it isn't working, you can use 'jQuery' instead, so-

```
<script>
var page={};
jQuery(function(){
    new FrontPage().init();
}); 
</script>
```

if you are trying to use the '$' for a different library, $.noConflict() would be the best route:

```
<script>
var page={};
$.noConflict();
$(function(){
    new FrontPage().init();
}); 
</script>
```